# How to remove Extra Black Lines

Tags: mesh, vertex-groups

I am a Beginner and was working on THE DOUGHNUT.
I get these black lines(refer to image) and cant even select them.
How do I get Rid of them?
[image]

Comment: It might be cause by rogue or double geometry, in edit mode and vertex select mode, select everything > Right click > merge > By distance

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @gorgious thank you very much.My problem was solved.Thank You very much.